# Ansible Regex Expression

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm looking to find all ports with a certain status on a Cisco router to shut them down. I was hoping to do this via std.out and using regex but have no idea on the regex syntax.

For example, output for the show command will look something like the below output.

```
 Port       Device          State   Call          DN        Dev State                          
---------- --------------- -------- ------------- ------- ----------- ----
0/1/0      DEV0001         IS       IDLE         2344       ATT
0/1/1      DEV0002         IS       IDLE         2567       ATT
0/1/2      DEV0002         IS       IDLE         2567       DEL
```

What I'd like to do is to store the port numbers which has Dev State = ATT in a variable so I can shut them down. In Cisco I can filter the show command to say - show port | include ATT - this will only list the ports that contain the Dev State ATT but it wont show any of the Column heading in the output. From this output, I then need to loop through and store the port numbers. Hope this makes sense.

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Ansible Script:

```
 tasks:
   - name: show port
     ios_command:
      commands:
        - show port summary | incl ATT
     register: config
   - set_fact
      myvalue: ""{{ config.stdout | regex_search(??) }}""
      when config.stdout | length > 0
```

Output of Debug config:

```
    "stdout_lines": [
        [
            "Total Devices:           4",
            "Total Calls in Progress: 0",
            "Total Call Legs in Use:  0",
            "",
            "Port       Device          Device   Call          Dev     Directory   Dev ",
            "Identifier Name            State    State         Type    Number      Cntl ",
            "---------- --------------- -------- ------------- ------- ----------- ---- ",
            "0/1/0      DEV0001         IS       IDLE          ALG     3880       DEL",
            "0/1/1      DEV0002         IS       IDLE          ALG     3881       ATT",
            "0/1/2      DEV0003         IS       IDLE          ALG                ATT",
            "0/1/3      DEV0004         IS       IDLE          ALG     3882       DEL"
        ]
    ]
} ]
```

Comment: Update your question with the output of - debug: var=config

Comment: I've added the stdout_lines output

Comment: `stdout_lines` is a list of list. You need the first item `stdout_lines.0`, obviously.

Comment: ok I still get a similar error as before after modifying the line 
cols: "{{ config.stdout_lines.0.split() }}"

 "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'split'\n\nThe error appears to have been in

Comment: `config.stdout_lines.0` is a list. It's not possible `split()` a list. My answer works fine with the first output example. It's not working with `stdout_lines` you posted. I'm not going to fix it. The names of the columns can't be used because "Device" is repeating. The lines with data can't be split because of one "Directory" item is missing. I'd expect Cisco to provide you with a format that can be parsed.

Comment: cols: "{{ config.stdout_lines.0.7.split() }}" works but that only gives one of the lines. so we need to loop to get the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- There should be [*`config.stdout_lines`*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ios_command_module.html#return-values) along with *`config.stdout`*
- It's not necessary to test the list. The loop will be skipped if the list is empty.
- Lines with data are selected by the pattern *`'^\d/\d/\d\s*(.*)$'`*
- It's possible to customize the result by changing the *`when`* condition and changing the list of *`myitems`* added the list *`myvalues`*

The tasks below

```
    - set_fact:
        myvalues: "{{ myvalues|default([]) + [myitems.4] }}"
      loop: "{{ config.stdout_lines|select('regex', myregex)|list }}"
      vars:
        myregex: '^\d/\d/\d\s*(.*)$'
        myitems: "{{ item.split() }}"
      when: myitems.5 == "ATT"
    - debug:
        var: myvalues
```

give

```
    "myvalues": [
        "2344", 
        "2567"
    ]
```

---

Generally, it's possible to create a list with the names of the columns and create ditionaries with selected data. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        cols: "{{ config.stdout_lines.0.split() }}"
    - set_fact:
        myvalues: "{{ myvalues|default([]) +
                      [dict(cols|zip(myitems))] }}"
      loop: "{{ config.stdout_lines|select('regex', myregex)|list }}"
      vars:
        myregex: '^\d/\d/\d\s*(.*)$'
        myitems: "{{ item.split() }}"
      when: myitems.5 == "ATT"
    - debug:
        var: myvalues
```

gives

```
    "myvalues": [
        {
            "Call": "IDLE", 
            "DN": "2344", 
            "Dev": "ATT", 
            "Device": "DEV0001", 
            "Port": "0/1/0", 
            "State": "IS"
        }, 
        {
            "Call": "IDLE", 
            "DN": "2567", 
            "Dev": "ATT", 
            "Device": "DEV0002", 
            "Port": "0/1/1", 
            "State": "IS"
        }
    ]
```

Then any combination of the data can be selected. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        myports: "{{ myvalues|json_query('[].Port') }}"
    - debug:
        var: myports
```

give the list of the Ports

```
    "myports": [
        "0/1/0", 
        "0/1/1"
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I need the find the ports that match the Call State, not the DN. So the output should be 0/1/0, 0/1/1 and so on.

Comment: Sure. Simply change `[myitems.4]` to `[myitems.0]`. Port is the first item in the list. I've added an example of how to create any selection.

Comment: yep I thought that would be case but I'm having problems executing the script. I get the below error

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [router1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ config.stdout_lines | select('regex', myregex)|list }}): expected string or buffer"}

Could it be because of the way the output gets formatted in IOS?

Comment: This below post says to use  output.stdout | join('') instead of stdout_lines but this gives me "myvalues": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" in the debug output. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737295/using-when-conditional-to-match-string-in-output-register-ansible

Comment: I tried your dictionaries code but I got the below error:

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [router1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'lines'\n\n